# How to use LIST_FOREACH_SAFE?

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list, freebsd

**Platform:**

Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, gcc, arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

**Library Used:**

FreeBSD library

**Question:**

I'm studying FreeBSD library.
([the reference](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/LIST_FOREACH_SAFE/))

I got the compile error when I used `LIST_FOREACH_SAFE`, I could not figure out how fix the bug.

**Wrong Output:**

```
test.c:39: error: ‘entries’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:39: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:39: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

int main()
{
    LIST_HEAD(listhead, entry) head =
        LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
    struct listhead *headp;                 /* List head. */
    struct entry {
        int a;
        LIST_ENTRY(entry) entries;      /* List. */
    } *n1, *n2, *n3, *np, *np_temp;

    LIST_INIT(&head);                       /* Initialize the list. */

    n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));      /* Insert at the head. */
    n1->a = 7;
    LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&head, n1, entries);

    n2 = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));      /* Insert after. */
    n2->a = 5;
    LIST_INSERT_AFTER(n1, n2, entries);

    n3 = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));      /* Insert before. */
    n3->a = 1;
    LIST_INSERT_BEFORE(n2, n3, entries);

    LIST_REMOVE(n2, entries);               /* Deletion. */
    free(n2);

    /* Forward traversal. */
    LIST_FOREACH(np, &head, entries) {
        printf("%d\n", np->a);
    }


    /* Safe forward traversal. */
    LIST_FOREACH_SAFE(np, &head, entries, np_temp) {
        // do somethings
        LIST_REMOVE(np, entries);
        free(np);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you pasted compiles on OS X (other than complaining about an unused variable *headp*.) I'm guessing the problem is that whatever implementation of queue.h you're using on Linux doesn't include the LIST_FOREACH_SAFE macro. Your compiler is probably treating it as an implicit declaration of a function, and then erroring out when it can't resolve 'entries' (since it's a struct member, and not, say, a variable.)

For example, using clang, if I modify your program such that instead of referencing LIST_FOREACH_SAFE, I reference the non-existent LIST_FOREACH_SAFE_BOGUS, I get a similar error:

```
/tmp/foreach.c:39:5: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'LIST_FOREACH_SAFE_BOGUS' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    LIST_FOREACH_SAFE_BOGUS(np, &head, entries, np_temp) {
    ^
/tmp/foreach.c:39:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'entries'
    LIST_FOREACH_SAFE_BOGUS(np, &head, entries, np_temp) {
                                       ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

The [Ubuntu 12.04 man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/queue.3.html) for their version of queue.h does not mention either FOREACH or FOREACH_SAFE for any of the data structures involved. It's unclear to me if you're using the system queue.h or explicitly using the FreeBSD version, but either way, I recommend you do a quick grep through queue.h to make sure it includes a LIST_FOREACH_SAFE macro. If you're using something other than the system-provided queue.h, you should also check your compilation paths to make sure the correct version is being included.